# How to stretch columns and their headers proportionally in ListView

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, listviewitem

Lets say that I create a few headers like this:

```
 this.grdUsers.Columns.Add("id");
   this.grdUsers.Columns.Add("username");
   this.grdUsers.Columns.Add("phone");
   this.grdUsers.Columns.Add("address");
```

and later on I add an item into list view  like this:

```
  ListViewItem parent;
      parent = this.grdUsers.Items.Add(user.id);
      parent.SubItems.Add(user.username);
      parent.SubItems.Add(user.phone);
      parent.SubItems.Add(user.address);

 I will end up with something like this:
```

[image]

but I am trying to achieve this actually:

[image]

After some reading I have find out about `HorizontalContentAlignment`, but I can't find it on `ListViewItem`...I am missing something obvious here? I am using `WinForm` application.

Comment: I've always had to use the control's client rectangle and just calculate them based on a percentage I assigned to each column.  Don't think there is an automated "fill to width" sort of thing.

Comment: @DonBoitnott Now that is sad I must say ... I mean, why such a simple feature would be missing? So, basically, you do those calculations every time when form is growing or shrinking, right?

Comment: @DonBoitnott By the way, what you said about using `ClientRectangle.Size`, worked.

Comment: Yes.  Typically, I would create a method to do the work, and just call it from wherever, including the `Resize` event(s).  And it's missing because what you want is `DataGridView` features in a control not meant to do it.

Comment: @DonBoitnott Well, maybe you are right. Maybe I should consider using DataGridView instead. Thanks for you help! If you find time, can you please show how your Resize() method would look like?

Answer (score 0):

I have end up with this:

```
 private void ResizeUserListHeaders()
 {
    var listViewWidth = this.grdUsers.ClientRectangle.Width;

    var headerWidth = listViewWidth / this.grdUsers.Columns.Count;

    foreach (ColumnHeader header in this.grdUsers.Columns)
    {

          header.Width = headerWidth;
    }
}
```

Then on form's ResizeEnd action:

```
 private void ResizeEndAction(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    this.ResizeUserListHeaders();
 }
```